# How to correctly get a partial dataframe of rows and then save it to a csv?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, text

First I read a csv and then get a partial dataframe from it (row 12~14), and then save it to another csv.
However it has warning afterwards saying 'A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame'
How should I get a partial dataframe and save it to another csv correctly?

```
    df = pd.read_csv(filename)

    df_min_part = df.iloc[12:14, : ]
    df_min_part.to_csv(filename + '_min_part.csv')
```

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the warning. It might happen somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`pandas.DataFrame.copy()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html) if you want to do operation on `df_min_part` later.

```py
df_min_part = df.iloc[12:14, : ].copy()
```